# Problemas ao passar parâmetro por POST pelo Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Estou tendo problemas ao passar parâmetros via POST para meus métodos em PHP. Tenho a variável em JS devidamente populada com os atributos que eu quero passar. Porém ao tentar acessar a variável em meu código PHP diz que ela esta indefinida. 
Estou utilizando o Codeigniter como framework.

Código JS:

```
var arr = [];
var vars = arr.concat(put, pedidoData);
$.ajax({
   url: "controller/metodo",
   type: 'POST',
   data: {vars:vars},
   success: function(r) {
     if (r.status == "success"){                                                       
         console.log("Sucesso");
     }else{
         console.log(vars);
         console.log("erro na inserçao");
         console.log(r);
     }
   }
});
```

Codigo do controller.php :

```
public function metodo(){
    $resposta = $this->input->post();
    $response = $this->meumodel_model->metodo($resposta);
    if(is_null($response)){
        $this->response(array("status"=>"erro", "erro"=>"Resposta nula ou vazia."), 200);
    }else{
        $this->response($response, 200);
    }
}
```

Código do meumodel_model.php:

```
  public function metodo($vars = array()){

    $variaveis = array();
    $inserir = "SQL utilizando as variaveis...";
    $q = $this->db->query($inserir); 

    if($q){
        return array("status"=>"success");
    }else{
        return array("status"=>"error");
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado. Grato.

Comment: o valor da url no Ajax não deveria estar entre aspas?

Comment: Sim, repassei errado para a pergunta, no código original está. Obrigado pelo alerta =D

Comment: Só pra conferir, tem certeza de que o erro é referente a variável? Pergunto para ter certeza que você usou o `$this->load->model('meu_model_model);` no seu método construtor, pois se não o fez, você está tentando chamar o model sem carregá-lo antes.

Comment: Olá o erro foi resolvido declarando o data_type, que no caso era um JSON